# What regular expression can be used to find long running urls the Google App Engine dashboard?

Tags: regex, google-app-engine

I would like to enter a regular expression in the Google App Engine dashboard to list all urls that are taking longer then 5000ms to return. All of the log data seems to be there and label-based regular expressions like these work to find all urls with status 404.

```
status:[404]\d\d
```

What regex expression can be used to find all logs where the time in ms is greater than 5000ms. I'm looking for something like this.

```
[5-9][0-9][0-9][0-9](ms|cpu_ms|api_cpu_ms)

Example logs:
    2011-10-16 23:36:35.574 /A 200 135ms 200cpu_ms 153api_cpu_ms 0kb Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; InfoPath.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
    2011-10-16 23:13:02.010 /B 200 301ms 135cpu_ms 65api_cpu_ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1
    2011-10-16 23:10:53.356 /C 304 22ms 0cpu_ms 0kb
    2011-10-17 22:14:15.043 /D 200 5977ms 7276cpu_ms 3636api_cpu_ms 3kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1
```

Comment: You know you aren't matching the `api_cpu_ms`, right?

Comment: Didn't think about checking for that as well. I added the option. Thanks.

Comment: Figured it out. What Google shows in the log summaries is not what is  in the logs. The summary says 5000ms but the actual logs says ms=5000. So the answer is just (ms=)([5-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]).

Comment: Be aware that that won't catch 10000ms :-) And I'm happy to know what I wrote was true `At this point I suspect there is a character between the numbers and the ms part that the copy/paste doesn't convey`

Comment: Correct. I am actually planning to use (ms=)([0-9]{5,}|[5-9][0-9]{3}) which seems to catch all the upper bound cases and also catches cpu_ms=5000+ and api_cpu_ms=5000+ cases.

Comment: And after a few weeks of practical use, I'm usually using ( ms=)([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]) which is highlighting any requests taking longer than 10 seconds to complete which none ever should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like this: `([0-9]{5,}|[5-9][0-9]{3})(ms|cpu_ms|api_cpu_ms)`? Or you want something more complex?

Link to test: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2uupn

If you want to match the whole line: `^.*([0-9]{5,}|[5-9][0-9]{3})(ms|cpu_ms|api_cpu_ms).*$` but remember to activate the multiline option of your regex engine

Link to test: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2uupq

Comment: This looks to be on the right track, but unfortunately it will not work in the Google App Engine log regex filter box.

Comment: @Chris Can you clarify "doesn't work"?  Is it showing too many records, not enough records, or does it generate an error message?

Comment: @Chris I'll add... Can you give us an example with the ms > 5000? Do Google add a thousand separator? (so 5,000ms)

Comment: @Chris Because it catches the `.NET CLR 2.0.50727` if you don't put the ms part

Comment: ([0-9]{5,}|[5-9][0-9]{3}) Returns too many results since it catches any numbers of a given length.  ([0-9]{5,}|[5-9][0-9]{3})(ms|cpu_ms|api_cpu_ms) Does not return any results but should. The example with ^.*(....).*$ does not return any results either. There are no , separators in the portions of the logs that I am analyzing.

Comment: @Chris try ([0-9]{5}|[5-9][0-9]{3})(ms|cpu_ms|api_cpu_ms)

Comment: @Chris Or `([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[5-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])(ms|cpu_ms|api_cpu_ms)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Nothing with (ms|cpu_ms|api_cpu_ms) at the end returns results and anything without that end catches the incorrect numbers. No sure how Google's log regex is parsing differently than the online regex parser.

Comment: Try searching for `(ms|cpu_ms|api_cpu_ms)`. It should match all the rows. At this point I suspect there is a character between the numbers and the ms part that the copy/paste doesn't convey (like a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-breaking_space for example)

Comment: Added my comment above to the problem. Google was reversing things in the summary. Thanks for all the help.